# find and replace a string in a JSON response in .Net

Tags: c#, json, regex

I am receiving the following type of *JSON* response from a web service:

```
{"students":[{"studentID":"123456789","section":"S","RefId":"     ","pastScore":"99952","currentScore":"99952","inquiryAllowed":true},{"studentID":"223456789","section":"R","RefId":"     ,"pastScore":"152","currentScore":"952","inquiryAllowed":true},{"studentID":"323456789","section":"T","RefId":"     ,"pastScore":"4582","currentScore":"5952","inquiryAllowed":true},],"schoolName":"WatsonPrimarySchool"}
```

I need to mask studentID, pastScore, currentScore and schoolName. The output will be like this:

```
{"students":[{"studentID":"$$$$$$$$","section":"S","RefId":"     ","pastScore":"$$$$$","currentScore":"$$$$$","inquiryAllowed":true},{"studentID":"$$$$$$$$$","section":"R","RefId":"     ,"pastScore":"$$$","currentScore":"$$$","inquiryAllowed":true},{"studentID":"$$$$$$$$$","section":"T","RefId":"     ,"pastScore":"$$$$","currentScore":"$$$$","inquiryAllowed":true},],"schoolName":"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"}
```

`schoolName` will occur only once while the rest can be multiple.

I tried using `StringBuilder` but due to the dynamic nature of values, it was not successful. Can someone please suggest a Regex solution?

Comment: Deserialize to an object and in the getter for those properties return `"$$$$$$"` or whatever

Comment: Go to http://json2csharp.com/ paste your json format, it will generate the class. Use Json.Net to convert the class to JSON and vise versa.

Comment: @DGibbs - I do agree that converting the response to a class and masking the value in the getter would be a good process, but due to a peculiar requirement, needed to handle the JSON string directly.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) and Linq

```
var propsToMask = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "studentID", "pastScore", "currentScore", "schoolName" });
var jObj = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach(var p in jObj.Descendants()
                     .OfType<JProperty>()
                     .Where(p => propsToMask.Contains(p.Name)))
{
    p.Value = "$$$$$$";
}

var newJsonStr = jObj.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not permitted to go for external components, so cannot use JSON.Net. Is there a .Net native class that do the same job?

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON.Net to convert the JSON to a class, mask the properties you want to mask, and again use JSON.Net to generate the JSON for the masked values

You can use any other library for JSON also, JSON.Net is just the simplest to use that I know of -- check licensing conditions also

Comment: It would have been nice that you provided an example with code.

Answer (score 0):

@DGibbs is a good tip.
But if you decide go to regex:

```
Regex.Replace(jsonInput, "((studentID|pastScore|currentScore|currentScore)\":\")(.+?)\"", "$1\$\$\$\"")
```

Comment: I used your suggestion. Done a slight change to overcome "unrecognized escape sequence" error. The output meets the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions:

1. Convert the string to object, then change it into whatever you want.
2. Do it directly using `StringBuilder`

**FIRST SOLUTION, USING JSON.NET:** here is the steps:

1. You should re-check your JSON, eliminate unneeded spaces. If your JSON contains them, like ' studentID', you cannot parse it correctly. Here is what I did:

   ```
   {
   'students' : [{
           'studentID' : '123456789',
           'section' : 'S',
           'RefId' : '     ',
           'pastScore' : '99952',
           'currentScore' : '99952',
           'inquiryAllowed' : true
       }, {
           'studentID' : '223456789',
           'section' : 'R',
           'RefId' : '     ',
           'pastScore' : '152',
           'currentScore' : '952',
           'inquiryAllowed' : true
       }, {
           'studentID' : '323456789 ',
           'section' : 'T',
           'RefId' : '',
           'pastScore' : '4582',
           'currentScore' : '5952',
           'inquiryAllowed' : true
       }
   ],
   'schoolName' : 'WatsonPrimarySchool'
   }
   ```
2. Use `Nuget Packages` to add Json.NET library to your project.
   [image: NewtonSoft]
3. Create 2 classes to hold your data:

**Student.cs**

```
public class Student
{
    public string StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public string RefId { get; set; }
    public string PastScore { get; set; }
    public string CurrentScore { get; set; }
    public bool InquiryAllowed { get; set; }
}
```

**School.cs**

```
public class School
{
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public string SchoolName { get; set; }
}
```

4. Main program.

   ```
       string json = "Your JSON string";

       // Convert JSON string to object
       var school = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<School>(json);

       // Mask it as you want
       foreach (var student in school.Students)
       {
           student.StudentId = "$$$$$$$$";
           student.PastScore = "$$$$$$$$";
           student.CurrentScore = "$$$$$$$$";
       }
       school.SchoolName = "$$$$$$$$";

       // Convert object back to string
       string masked = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(school);

       // Show it
       Console.WriteLine(masked);

       Console.ReadLine();
   ```

**SECOND SOLUTION: USING `StringBuilder`**

First, you **must** check your JSON string to make sure it has a correct format. I did it in the first step above. For testing reason, I replace all double quote with single quote.

Here is the program, using `StringBuilder`. I put comments there. If you don't understand, feel free to ask.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = "{'students':[{'studentID':'123456789','section':'S','RefId':'     ','pastScore':'99952','currentScore':'99952','inquiryAllowed':true},{'studentID':'223456789','section':'R','RefId':'     ','pastScore':'152','currentScore':'952','inquiryAllowed':true},{'studentID':'323456789 ','section':'T','RefId':'','pastScore':'4582','currentScore':'5952','inquiryAllowed':true}],'schoolName':'WatsonPrimarySchool'}";
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    // The cursor
    int start = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        bool notFoundStudentId = false;
        bool notFoundPastScore = false;
        bool notFoundCurrentScore = false;

        // Student ID
        int index = json.IndexOf("'studentID'", start, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (index > 0)
        {
            // Append everything from the starting point to the beginning of 'studentID'
            builder.Append(json, start, index - start);

            // Mask it
            builder.Append("'studentID':'$$$$$$'");

            // Move the starting point to the comma after 'studentID' value
            start = json.IndexOf(',', index);
        }
        else
        {
            notFoundStudentId = true;
        }

        // Past score
        index = json.IndexOf("'pastScore'", start, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (index > 0)
        {
            builder.Append(json, start, index - start);
            builder.Append("'pastScore':'$$$$$$'");
            start = json.IndexOf(',', index);
        }
        else
        {
            notFoundPastScore = true;
        }

        // Current Score
        index = json.IndexOf("'currentScore'", start, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        if (index > 0)
        {
            builder.Append(json, start, index - start);
            builder.Append("'currentScore':'$$$$$$'");
            start = json.IndexOf(',', index);
        }
        else
        {
            notFoundCurrentScore = true;
        }

        // Found nothing? It's time for schoolName
        if (notFoundStudentId && notFoundPastScore && notFoundCurrentScore)
        {
            index = json.IndexOf("'schoolName'", start, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            builder.Append(json, start, index - start);
            builder.Append("'schoolName':'$$$$$$'}");

            // End the loop
            break;
        }
    }

    // Display
    Console.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: appreciate your time, but as I mentioned already, due to a peculiar requirement, need to handle the JSON string directly.

Comment: OK, I'll do it directly :)

Comment: Sure. I will try to validate both Regex solution and string builder solution for performance and update.

Comment: Did you take a look at my StringBuilder solution? Did it help?

Comment: I was pushed to another task due to some urgency. So, could not test the string builder solution and compare. I will update you immediately once I am able to test.

Comment: Got time to test the stringbuilder solution, AnhTriet! It worked equally well. Tested with a small load though.